# Collapsible Content in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple collapsible content element at the top of a page that has a list view. The html works fine.

My problem is that if a user opens the collapsible block, I'd like it to automatically close when the user leaves or comes back to the page. The collapsible block always remains as the user has left it--open. I don't know how to close it. I've searched for a couple of days, but can't find the exact scenario. Most of the solutions that I've found deal with dynamic loading of pages and they are a little too advanced for me to understand.

I know this is probably a simple thing, but I'm so new to jquery mobile. I don't know how to bind the code to the html element or where to put it so please work me though with baby steps.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi in my jqm web app I close programmatically collapsible block like this:

$('.ui-collapsible').trigger('collapse');

You should bind pageshow event like this :

```
$('#your_page_id').bind('pageshow', function(){

            $('.ui-collapsible').trigger('collapse');

       });
```

for example you can try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjwtD/)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Especially with the jsFiddle code. Sadly, I still can't get it to work. My page opens and the collapsible content is closed. I open the content and move to another page. Then go back and the collapsible content is still open. Guess I just don't get it. The page id is correct and the code was pasted into the right place. Don't know much more to do. I will keep trying to study what you've provided. Thanks again. -Rachel

Comment: Got it! :-) Thank you! Here is what I did:  </br?     jQuery('#my_page').live('pagehide', function () {
 $('#closed').trigger('collapse');
 });' Not sure if I should use .live or .bind, but it is working. I sure appreciate the help. Whew--my head is aching from trying to understand this stuff. -Rachel

Answer (score 1):

this works with jQM 1.4 :

```
$('#yourdivId').collapsible('collapse');
```

one can do this:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#yourpageId", function () {
  $('#yourdivId').collapsible('collapse');
})
```